# WPF: Stop Animation For Hidden Controls on Windows Load

Tags: wpf, storyboard

I have a very simple fade in/out animation which works fine using data triggers. I have bind the data trigger to a bool property and inside trigger it  set the opacity to 0 on false and vice versa.

Now the problem is the objects whose bool value is false upon loading, I don't expect them to show on load and then animate themselves to hide.

I have tried to set the opacity to 0 on style setter but no use

Here is the button style

```
        <Style x:Key="LocationPickerButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="93"/>
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="93"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid >
                            <Image x:Name="DefaultImage" Source="something.png"/>
                           <Ellipse x:Name="HitTest" Fill="Transparent" Height="93" Width="93" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLocationVisible}" Value="true">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="showSelectedLocation">
                                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" From="0" To="1"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="showSelectedLocation"></StopStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLocationVisible}" Value="false">
                                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="hideSelectedLocation">
                                        <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" From="1" To="0" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </BeginStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="hideSelectedLocation"></StopStoryboard>
                                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
```

Comment: I was trying to do something similar (preventing an animation from occurring if another datatrigger was true) but all I could do was stop it if it had started with the StopStoryboard.

Comment: Do you need the button whose bool value is false to be immediately collapsed upon loading? There's a workaround for the animation but then it will still take the `Animation Duration` time before the button gets collapsed.

Comment: @Funk Yes I want it collapsed on load, user could bring it back by choosing specific options and then it needs to work with the specified animation, To put it in better terms, I just don't want it to execute data trigger on load as I am not settings the associated property to false manually, it just have the default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do these changes in your XAML :

1. Shift your `DataTriggers` from `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` to  `Style.Triggers`.
2. Set `Opacity = 0` in `Style Setter` as starting `Opacity` for every `Button`.
3. Remove `From = 1` in `false DataTrigger`.

With all the changes, your `Style` would look like this :

```
    <Style x:Key="LocationPickerButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLocationVisible}" Value="true">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="showSelectedLocation">
                            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity">
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" From="0" To="1"/>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="showSelectedLocation"></StopStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLocationVisible}" Value="false">
                    <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard x:Name="hideSelectedLocation">
                            <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" >
                                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1"  To="0" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="hideSelectedLocation"></StopStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Style.Setters>
                <Setter Property="Height" Value="93"/>
                <Setter Property="Width" Value="93"/>
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="0"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Grid >
                                <Image x:Name="DefaultImage" Source="something.png"/>
                                <Ellipse x:Name="HitTest" Fill="Transparent" Height="93" Width="93" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>                                    
                                <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                                <Trigger Property="Opacity" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"></Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
```

Comment: Almost there, the animation will still trigger on start up when default is false. To suppress this remove the `From="1"` in the DoubleAnimation of the second DataTrigger.

Comment: @Funk I did that in my test example, but forgot to mention here.

Comment: @AnjumSKhan Works like a charm. Thanks